# Find the most recent file on a http server (python)

Tags: python, file, http

I have a site: http://planet.osm.ch/replication/hour/000/006/ and I need to get the most recent file listed on the server.  How can I accomplish this through python 2.6.x and using only the standard library.

Thank you

Edit:

When I mean the most recent, I mean the most recent files listed by the date field.

Answer (score 2):

Many people prefer to use Beautiful Soup for these tasks. But since you want to use only the standard library , here is a quick solution using the re and urllib2 modules.

```
import urllib2
import re
page = urllib2.urlopen(Your_site).read()
print re.findall(r"<a.+>(\d+.+)</a>",page)[-1]
```

Note : I know it is bad practice to use re to parse HTML, but this is a simple website and the question requires so.

Comment: afaik the most recent is going to be [-1] not [0] (+1 all the same)

Comment: also it is unclear what he means by "get most recent" if he just wants the name of it this answers it ... if he wants to download it he is still one step away ...

Comment: I assumed the newest file would be on top. I'm sorry .

Comment: Im not sure if its standardized or not but for me when I click his link its on bottom ... allthough I have no idea if you can count on this being the case always